# How to set a string property to QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a list of application specific items uniquely identified by an id. Their names are displayed in a `QTreeWidget` (one item corresponds to a single `QTreeWidgetItem`). I would like to somehow attach the corresponding ids to these `QTreeWidgetItems` so that upon selection changed I can access the id of the corresponding item and do some processing.

`QTreeWidgetItem` does not inherit from `QObject` so I cannot use its `setProperty` function. How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create some user defined [roles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for the properties...

```
typedef enum {
  id_1_role = Qt::UserRole,
  id_2_role,

  id_N_role,
} property_id_role;
```

Then you can use the normal means of getting/setting the data associated with a `QTreeWidgetItem`.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = ...

/*
 * Set the property value.
 */
item->setData(column, property_id_role::id_2_role, id_2_value);

/*
 * Get the property value.
 */
auto id_2_value = item->data(column, property_id_role::id_2_role).value<id_2_type>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you know that QTreeWidgetItem has a setData method?

```
setData(int column, int role, const QVariant &value)
```

You can use it with your roles. For example:

```
int your_id = 123;
ui->treeWidget->currentItem()->setData(0,Qt::UserRole,your_id);
qDebug() << ui->treeWidget->currentItem()->data(0,Qt::UserRole);
```